# Delete Rows After a Certain Point in R

Tags: r, dataset, row

I have a data set where I'd like to delete the rows after a certain column value comes up

An example of the data set:

```
a<-data.frame(Account=c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A'),
              ProcessDate=seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),as.Date('2020-09-01'),by='month'),
              Payment=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
              ColumnCriteria=c(610,610,610,610,610,650,610,610,610))
```

I would like to delete the rows after the ColumnCriteria = 650.

My problem is that I'm working with a large data set so I cannot just use the `filter` function with a few `lags` because where the 650 is in this example, will be different for another Account.

I'm thinking I could potentially write an `if_else` statement where if the ColumnCriteria is equal to 650 then return the Date and then I could try to fill the column with that date and then filter the rows where the ProcessDate is greater. This seems a little messy so I figured I'd reach out and see if anyone had any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `ColumnCriteria` definition is missing a value.

Comment: Is 650 guaranteed to appear only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [`slice`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html):

```
library(dplyr)

slice(a, 1:which(ColumnCriteria == 650, arr.ind = TRUE))

  Account ProcessDate Payment ColumnCriteria
1       A  2020-01-01       1            610
2       A  2020-02-01       2            610
3       A  2020-03-01       3            610
4       A  2020-04-01       4            610
5       A  2020-05-01       5            610
6       A  2020-06-01       6            650
```

Note: If the cutoff value appears multiple times, this expression will only use the first instance of that value (ordered by the row order of `a`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this `base R` solution by creating an index with `which()`:

```
#Data
a<-data.frame(Account=c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A'),
              ProcessDate=seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),as.Date('2020-09-01'),by='month'),
              Payment=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
              ColumnCriteria=c(610,610,610,610,610,650,610,610,610))   
#Index
i <- min(which(a$ColumnCriteria==650))
#Code
a2 <- a[1:i,]
```

Output:

```
a2
  Account ProcessDate Payment ColumnCriteria
1       A  2020-01-01       1            610
2       A  2020-02-01       2            610
3       A  2020-03-01       3            610
4       A  2020-04-01       4            610
5       A  2020-05-01       5            610
6       A  2020-06-01       6            650
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you need to operate by `Account`, and that your data is implicitly ordered by `Payment`, although you didn't supply a complete enough dataset to really demonstrate this. Are you familiar with `dplyr::group_by()`?

```
a %>%
  group_by(Account) %>%
  arrange(Payment) %>%
  filter(cumsum(tidyr::replace_na(lag(ColumnCriteria == 650), 0)) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `match` and `seq`

```
a[seq_len(match(650, a$ColumnCriteria)),]
#  Account ProcessDate Payment ColumnCriteria
#1       A  2020-01-01       1            610
#2       A  2020-02-01       2            610
#3       A  2020-03-01       3            610
#4       A  2020-04-01       4            610
#5       A  2020-05-01       5            610
#6       A  2020-06-01       6            650
```